# jQuery sortable with deferred rendering

Tags: jquery, dom, deferred-rendering

I use a jQuery plugin (DataTable with Scroller extension) that allows me to display HTML `table` with thousand lines thanks to a defer rendering.

I want to make it `sortable` (with sortable jQuery-UI plugin).

The issue is that when I drag an element and want to drop it far away lower, the first `nodes` of the table disappears from the DOM and the new ones appears. So I'm no longer able to drop the dragged element.

An exemple is better than long texts : http://jsfiddle.net/91dr6utg/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data:           data,
        deferRender:    true,
        dom:            "frtiS",
        scrollY:        200,
        scrollCollapse: true
    } );
    
    $('#example tbody').sortable({
        helper: "clone",
        start: function (event, ui) {
            ui.item.appendTo($('#dragSave'));
            ui.helper.appendTo($('#dragSave'));
        },
    }).disableSelection();
});

var data = [ "A lot of datas !" ];
```

```html
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>ZIP / Post code</th>
            <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<div id="dragSave"></div>
```

(try it in jsfiddle.net, there is too many lines to be allowed in the snippet)

If I drag the fist element, I can't drop it after the 90th element.

---

#### More information :

I did the `start` function to prevent that the dragged line disappears. Indeed, if the original `node` is removed from the DOM, the `sortable` plugin can no longer drop the element (it doesn't know it anymore). So I move it in another container of the DOM which is never updated.

If we remove this function, we'll see that the original `node` is removed approx fifty lines lower
=> Ok that comes from the DOM regeneration
BUT we can still drop the element until ninety line lower
=> because the next lines where never generated in the DOM, it's the limit

Answer (score 0):

I found a way whithout using `sortable()`, but using `draggable()`.

Here it is : http://jsfiddle.net/2dtcy9bs/1/

Comment: The new issue is the use on Firefox ... which does really weird things ... On chrome everythings is fine